# SQL Stored Procedure for Importing Text files as tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a folder full of text files that are tab delimited.  However, each has a lot of columns that can change.  What I am looking for is a way to bring in these text files with the column names (1st row).  In a perfect world the code would loop through all of the files I have in a folder (DemographicsPL) and import them in as tables with the original name.  I know their has to be a way to do this.  Access can do this in one line of code and I know SQL is better than Access.

I would like to do other things with so I would like to do this in a stored procedure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm kind of a newbie to SQL.  The code below works but requires that the file already exist

```
--**** This works but is on local drive and reguires table to already exist.*****
BULK INSERT [dbo].[TR15] FROM '\\MA000XSREA01\E$\TDLoad\DemographicsPL\BG15.txt'
WITH (
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is it about SQL Server or MySQL ? Please update your tags.

Comment: If you don't know the names of the files, you are probably best off using the `bcp` utility and writing an shell script to execute the files.  Otherwise, you can use the `xp_` commands to get information on files.

Comment: This can be also done using SSIS component of your SQL Server. Otherwise, you could use PowerShell if you have that option available as well. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3208/automating-flat-file-sql-server-imports-with-powershell/

Comment: It is SQL Server.  Sorry about that.  I do know the names of the files but in a perfect world this would just be a loop of all of the files in the folder.  I don't know anything about Power Shell or SSIS.  Working with Stored Procedures is adventurous enough for me at the moment.   Must be a way to do this in a stored procedure.  Any examples Gordon?  I've seen some stuff about bcp but not sure how to call it in a stored procedure or how it can allow me to import it in as a table.  I've seen where you can use it to insert into an existing table though.